# Override parent setter method for parent instance variable in Child in python

Tags: python

I have a parent class called singleExperimentData with a few parameters, one of them is OD:

```
class singleExperimentData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__t = np.array([])
        self.__OD = None

    @property
    def OD(self):
        return self.__OD

    @OD.setter
    def OD(self, OD):
        self.__OD = OD
        self.checkTimeVectors()
```

I have another parent class which inherits from singleExperimentData, but I want to override the setter so that it doesn't call checkTimeVectors:

```
class singleExperimentDataShell(singleExperimentData):
    @singleExperimentData.OD.setter
    def OD(self, OD):
        self.__OD = OD
```

I'm wondering if this is the correct syntax? When I look through the variables, it seems I have a few different ones:

```
_singleExperimentData_OD = [data as expected]
OD = None
```

I first set OD as a timeCourseObject() with the following function:

```
self.avg = singleExperimentDataShell()
self.avg.OD = timeCourseObject()
self.avg.OD.dataVec = data
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dataVec'
```

Note that "None" is the default data type in singleExperimentData, but even though I have set it to a timeCourseObject, it doesn't seem to work. I feel like I'm doing something wrong with setters and getters but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using double-underscore names like `__OD`?  Those are meant for class-private variables, so if your base class defines `__OD`, subclasses will not (easily) be able to access that attribute.  If you change your attribute to `_OD` (single underscore), does it do what you want?

Comment: I replaced the double underscore with a single one and it seemed to work. Can you explain the difference between single and double underscore? Is single underscore protected while double is private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered, double-underscore names are "mangled".  This can be used to create class-private attributes which subclasses are "prevented" from accessing.  (I put "prevented" in quotes because the prevention can be circumvented.)  This behavior is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers).

Single-underscore names do not have this behavior.  The single underscore is purely a convention indicating an attribute that is not part of a class's public API.

You shouldn't use double-underscore attribute names unless you really want to restrict them to access *only* by the class in which they occur (not subclasses).